# Wordpress blog code format

Tags: admin

I am new to wordpress and I just created a new blog(free version). Now It seems that code fromat doesn't work. All lines are aligned to the left.
Please look at the image below.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in either `code` or `pre` tags. `code` is for when inline code in a sentence e.g. `include("hello.php")` whereas `pre` is for preformatted blocks of text e.g.:

```
function hello_world(){
    echo 'hello world';
}
```

For code highlighting etc, you'll need to look for plugins.

The easiest way of using these tags is using the preformatted style:

[image]

Comment: In HTML(not Visual), I added code tag but no luck.

Comment: That won't work, for example if I look at your screenshot I see you trying to use <code> for a block of code, which is not the correct usage at all. Reread my answer. Use <pre>

Comment: There is no pre tags on the menu, should I type in manually?

Comment: You can type it in manually, or in the styles dropdown, choose preformatted, see my answer for a screenshot

Comment: If I choice a plugin, how to? I downloaded one to my C drive, but where is the good place for it?

Comment: Try one of these: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/ or http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/